# Using code with the GPL v3 licence

Tags: android, licensing

I'm currently reading through this book Beginning Android Games by Mario Zechner and he has provided many base framework classes for games in his book. He also states that the source code is licensed under the GPL version 3. What does this mean for me if I wish to develop and release a game using his provided framework classes?

Thank you.

Comment: Oh come on, did you even punch "gpl v3" into Google? (Disclaimer for white knights: I know basic questions with little research can also be useful if they get a great answer and end up on the first page of Google, but we already have numerous well-answered questions on the GPL, without even considering the countless other resources.)

Comment: Exactly. Derivate works under the same license, obligation to leave your code open etc. etc. Research effort is paramount as well.

Comment: Yeah I did, I'm honestly hopeless when it comes to these licensing things. I know LGPL is very non-restrictive but I couldn't differentiate between the different GPL versions.

Comment: *In short:* if you want to sell your product and don't want other people to be able to see your code and "copy-paste" it as another game, stay away from the GPL. And no, I'm not against the GPL (au contraire), but when people don't know about it, it generally means that's what they want to know, to put it simply.

Comment: I don't get much from the license terms itself either. But there are great explanations all over the net, and there's an official FAQ for the GPL and related licenses which spells out what it means for some specific scenarios.

Comment: @DavidCesarino Your phrasing is technically correct, but since I've seen people extrapolate the wrong things from similar explanations, I'll chip in anyway: The GPL does, in no way, prohibit or even address commercial use. It just also gives users the right to re-distribute and change the work, which is obviously a problem for many business models. As for copy-pasting: Like other FOSS licenses, the GPL requires keeping the attribution, and the GPL specifically also requires keeping it under GPL when re-distributin derivative work - IOW outright *stealing* is actually illegal.

Comment: @delnan: You're spot on on extrapolating, and that problem go all the way down to how law is interpreted. And wording can only go so far, because some concepts (*derivative works*, I believe, comes from jurisprudence construction of the Genebra Convention and each country's laws) will be defined as final by a judge in the extreme outcome (litigation).

Comment: @DavidCesarino Absolutely true and important, but that's not what I'm talking about here. I'm concerned about GPL noobs reading statements like yours without further explanation, and take from that "GPL prohibits commercial use" (completely false) or "GPL allows anyone to copy the source code as they want" (IMHO the wrong interpretation, though the effect on your business model can be similar).

Comment: No worries, I know. :) Btw, that's why I put "copy-past" in quotes. But yeah, I completely understand that. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm no lawyer, but I have had to deal with GPL licensing before. Basically, it means if you use any of the code, you have to distribute the derivative work under the same license terms.

Side note: You ARE allowed to charge a fee for the software, even though you have to release the source code.

Comment: That's a really rough approximation. Well, I've seen worse (actively wrong, like saying it prohibits commercial use), but you could at least mention the rights it gives to each user.

Comment: Thank you ajpolt and David Cesarino, makes it much more clear now.

Comment: You're right, delnan. But from a practical perspective as a developer, I'd want to know what the restrictions are before deciding whether to move forward. I think what I wrote are the most important practical restrictions.

Comment: @ajpolt The thing is, the rights granted to users *are* restrictions (on what restrictions one can place upon users). For example, it's *very* important for me that users can create derivative works, but cannot distribute it under any license except the GPL.

Comment: @delnan Ah, you see, I was thinking that the phrase "you have to distribute the derivative work under the same license terms" covers that. Clearly if you can create a derivative work, and have to release it under the same license, then by recursion your users can (and/or have to) do the same.